# python importing class from python package

Tags: python, import, package

I am using python in a cgi enviroment and I use the mvc design pattern.
So i currently have the following hierarchy:

```
  main.py
  mvc/                         
  __init__.py               
  model/                  
          __init__.py
          session_initiator.py
  view/
          __init__.py
  controller/
          __init__.py
          interface.py
```

In session_initiator.py I have defined the class session_initiator
I am trying to import session_initiator class inside interface.py
The following code in interface.py is successful:

```
 from .. import model
```

but when I try adding anything like:

```
from model import session_initiator
```

I get an error that model is not a module.

Please don't refer to solutions regarding sys.path
because I am using an enviroment where I am unable to edit it.

Thanks.

**Edit**: all the init files are empty.

**Edit**: I changed the line to:

```
from  mvc.model import session_initator
```

and this line works!
But now when trying to do:

```
self.session_init = session_initiator()
```

I get the following error:

```
 TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Comment: You need to do `from mvc.model import session_initiator`

Comment: Not saying that you should do this to solve your problem, but you should always be able to edit `sys.path` dynamically from within Python itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Imports don't build on existing names like that.

```
from ..model import session_initiator
```

Also, `session_initiator` is now a module, not a class. If you meant to import something from *inside* that module then you must do so.

```
from ..model.session_initiator import session_initiator
```